# How can I remove these stainless steel scratches?

Tags: repair, steel, stainless, scratches, polish

I'm trying to fix a repair gone awry. I noticed some scratches on my stainless steel range of unknown origin. Things like cookware never touch that part of the stove, and I never use abrasive cleaners on it, but I digress. I want them gone.

Did some research and most DIY guides and products say to apply a mild abrasive (scotch brite is common) with the grain until it buffs out. [Bob Vila](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/how-to-remove-scratches-from-stainless-steel/) here said to use a microfiber cloth with barkeepers friend, which I had.

I followed his guide but (to my shock) it made it far worse! Here's the after. You can see the original scratches going up and down across the grain:

[image]

Yikes! What happened? What can I do?

Comment: To hide scratches you will need to create uniform scratches (scotch brite) or polish them completely out very tough to do in both cases.

Comment: Try diamond dust glass polishing compound. In comes in a mineral oil vehicle.

Comment: Very thin scratches you could try to polish out with toothpaste but it will be time consuming.

Comment: try very fine sandpaper, like 800 grit or higher, use a sanding block and sand in one direction. That will give you a brushed look.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell from the picture, but ideally, if you can remove that piece and work on it freely, here's what you can do:

1. Use a scotch brite pad and uniformly create scratches (the trick is to always always go in the same direction). [This pad here](http://amzn.to/2i24J3P) is commonly used to mimic #4 finish in stainless steel. You can also go to heavier / coarser pads.

[image]

2. If you actually have gouges, and assuming you have access to an orbital sander, [like this one (example)](http://amzn.to/2i0WULy), you would use a [heavier grit pad](http://amzn.to/2Ak07y2) to blend in all the scratches, then gradually go to a finer grit, [600 / 800](http://amzn.to/2juVARs) or so, to make all the scratches disappear. Then you can, if you want, put a grain on it again with the scotch brite pad.

[image][image]

3. To finish it up, you can clean the stainless steel with [stainless steel cleaner and polish.](http://amzn.to/2nfdrkF)

   [image: stainless steel cleaner and polish.]